# Значение куска кода

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, php, sql

Есть кусок кода из страницы аутентификации:

```
// Запрос к базе данных, чтобы проверить,
// существует ли соответствующая запись
$query = "select count (*) from auth where
name = ' $name ' and
pass = ' $password' " ;
$result = mysql_query ( $query ) ;
if (!$result)
{
    echo 'Cannot run query.';
    exit;
}
$count = mysql_result ( $result, 0, 0 );
if ( $count > 0 )
{
    // Комбинация имени и пароля посетителя правильная
    echo "<hl>Here it is !</hl>" ;
    echo "I bet you are glad you can see this secret page.";
}
else
{
    // Комбинация имени и пароля посетителя не правильная
    echo "<hl>Go Away ! </hl>" ;
    echo "You are not authorized to view this resource.";
}
```

Поясните мне его пожалуйста, **уделив особенное внимание оператору в этом куске кода (именно он мною понимается как-то размыто)**

```
$count = mysql_result ( $result, 0, 0 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Создается запрос SQL чтобы узнать количество (count) совпадений $name и $password

```
$query = "select count (*) from auth where
name = ' $name ' and
pass = ' $password' " ;
```

2) Выполняем запрос в переменную result

```
$result = mysql_query ( $query ) ;
```

3) Если результата нет(false) - невозможно выполнит запрос. Выход.

```
if (!$result)
{
    echo 'Cannot run query.';
    exit;
}
```

4) В переменную count выводим результат запроса query, если комбинация name и password встречается в базе, то count покажет сколько раз

```
$count = mysql_result ( $result, 0, 0 );
```

5) Если встречается больше 0 раз тогда

```
if ( $count > 0 )
{
    // Комбинация имени и пароля посетителя правильная
    echo "<hl>Here it is !</hl>" ;
    echo "I bet you are glad you can see this secret page.";
}
```

6) иначе:

```
else
{
    // Комбинация имени и пароля посетителя не правильная
    echo "<hl>Go Away ! </hl>" ;
    echo "You are not authorized to view this resource.";
}
```

P.S.> http://www.php.su/mysql_result

P.S.> Используйте `var_dump( переменная );` и вставляйте после кусков непонятного кода - это выведет значение переменной(массива) для прояснения ситуации.